# A better way to implement this for loop in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I need to list numbers from 1 to x in the format like

2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7 ......

I thought of a loop like

```
for(i =1; i <j+1; i=i+2)
{
    if (i < j)
        printf("%d ", i);

    printf("     %d \n", (i-1));
}
```

This seems to primitve.

In my system, In certain cases I would have to access the numbers in ascending order (0,1,2,3,4,...) and in certain cases I have to acceses the number in the order mentioned above.

I thought of just changing the for loop style based on the case.

Can you suggest a better way to implement this loop.

Thanks

Comment: I'm really confused. You need the numbers in a row like 1,2,3,4,5? or it needs to be in the order 2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7?

Comment: I need to access in the order like 2,1,4,3,6,5 ...

Comment: Are you sure about `\n` is inside `for` ?

Comment: I just wrote a sample code to print the numbers, all I am trying to test is the for loop.

Answer (score 6):

```
for(i=2; i<=j; i=i+2)
    printf("%d %d", i, i-1);
```

Comment: This would work only when j is an even number, if j is an odd number, we would have skipped the last number

Comment: @user2003172 so add checks for that edge case in there. What's the problem with that?

Answer (score 3):

```
int i, x;
printf("input x : ");
scanf("%d", &x);
for(i=1; i <= x; ++i){
    printf("%d ", i & 1 ? i+1 : i-1);
}
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

The loop can be written in various ways. For example the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int x;

    scanf( "%d", &x );

    for ( int i = 1, j = 1; i <= x; i++, j = -j )
    {
        printf( "%d ", i + j );
    }
    puts( "" );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter 10 then the output will be

```
2 1 4 3 6 5 8 7 10 9
```

Comment: When x is 5, the o/p is 2 1 4 3 6 , the logic seemed to skip the last number if its odd.

Comment: @user2003172 Do you need that the last value would be exactly x?

Answer (score 1):

As your wish use "\n". And use code something like this. You will get serious like what you asked. But careful with "\n"..

```
 Int a=0;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
          a=a+1;
          if(a%2==1){
              printf("%d \n",i+1);
          }else{
               printf("%d \n",i-1);
          }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a block of code inside the loop that needs to run once for every value in your list, it's possible to generate one item in the list per iteration with the following code. This prevents repetition.

```
int i, j = 10;
for (i = 2; i <= j; i += -1 + 4 * (i%2)) {
    printf("%d, ",i);
}
```

Comment: This seems to a good solution, but if J is an odd number , we would miss to print the last number.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean? It works fine for me.

Comment: j = 10  o/P : 2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9 if J=11 O/P: 2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9

Answer (score 1):

A simple offering

```
int i, x;
scanf("%d", &x);

// Loop from 1 to the largest even number <= x
for(i = 1; i <= (x & ~1); i++) {
  printf("%d ", i - 1 + 2*(i%2));
}
if (i <= x) {
  printf("%d ", i);
}
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using an array and an initializing for loop like so:

```
int array[size];

int n;
for(n = 0; n < size; n++){
  array[n] = n;
}
```

Then you can step into the array like so:

Go forward two; print.
Go back one; print;

etc.

some code for that may look like this:

```
int i = 0; //Which can be changed based on starting array number, etc.
while(i < size);
  printf("%d ", array[i]);
  if(i % 2 == 0){
    i--;
  } else {
    i += 3;
  }
```